# Django - How can I iterate over the options with modelform?

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms

I'm having a problem here I hope you could help..

Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

Basically I have a little web application where I have 3 forms.

one main form where I'm asking for `name` and `age`
one form for an old man and one more form for a young man

the first form I'll see in template will be the first form, where I'll enter the `name` and select if it's an old or young man.

to make it work as expected once I select `young` or `old` it will show with Jquery the corresponding `form` if I enter `old` I'll see form for old man and if I enter young I'll see the form for young man.

Jquery and everything works ok except by the first form..

All I need is to show my first form in template as a `modelform`.

I know I can make it work perfect with a normal form, but I need to save `age` and `name` in my database.

Here's my models :

```
AGES = (
('OLD', 'OLD'),
('YOUNG', 'YOUNG '),
)


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    age = models.CharField(max_length=128,choices=AGES, default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Questions_old(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    country = models.TextField()
    hobbies = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.person.name


class Questions_young(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    country = models.TextField()
    parents = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.person.name
```

my forms:

```
class personForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model =  Person
        fields = ["age","name"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(personForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['age'].choices = [(e.id, e.age) for e in Person.objects.all()]

class person_oldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Questions_old
        exclude = ('name',)
        fields = ['country','hobbies']

class person_youngForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Questions_young
        exclude = ('name',)
        fields = ['country','parents']
```

views:

```
def person_form(request):
    form1 = personForm(request.POST or None)
    form2 = person_oldForm(request.POST or None)
    form3 = person_youngForm(request.POST or None)
    queryset1 = Person.objects.all()
    queryset2 = Questions_old.objects.all()
    queryset3 = Questions_young.objects.all()
    context = {
    "form1": form1,
    "form2": form2,
    "form3": form3,
    "queryset1": queryset1,
    }
    form1_valid = form1.is_valid()
    form2_valid = form2.is_valid()
    form3_valid = form3.is_valid()
    if form1.is_valid():
        person = form1.save()
        if form2_valid:
            qo = form2.save(commit=False)
            qo.person = person
            qo.save()
        if form3_valid:
            qy = form3.save(commit=False)
            qy.person = person
            qy.save()
    return render(request, "person.html", context)
```

template:

```
<div class="form-group">
<select id="age" name="age">
{% for x,y in form.fields.age.choices %}
    <option value="{{ x }}"{% if form.fields.age.value == x %} selected{% endif %}>{{ y }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
</div>



      <div id="form" class="ages" style="display:none;">
        <form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
          {{ form2|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" name="submit"  class="btn  btn-success btn-xs">
      <span class="fa fa-floppy-o"></span> Guardar
    </button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div id="form1" class="ages" style="display:none;">
        <form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
          {{ form3|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" name="submit"  class="btn  btn-success btn-xs">
      <span class="fa fa-floppy-o"></span> Guardar
    </button>
        </form>
      </div>


      <script>
       $('#age').on('change',function(){
        if( $(this).val()==="old"){
          $("#form").show()
        }
        else{
          $("#form").hide()
        }
        if( $(this).val()==="young"){
          $("#form1").show()
        }
        else{
          $("#form1").hide()
        }
      });

     </script>
```

When I run my code I got an empty `select` , it's not showing my select as expected..

How can I make it work well?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Do you have any entries in your `Person` table currently? Looks like you're using the items in that table as your choices.

Comment: If you just want to show old and young, removing the `__init__` method for `personForm` should work since django will pick the choices from your model field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `__init__` method of your `personForm`. You're setting choices from the entries of the model.

```
self.fields['age'].choices = [(e.id, e.age) for e in Person.objects.all()]
```

Instead you should make django pick your choices from the model field choices. For that, you don't have to define a `__init__` method at all. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types):

> If the model field has choices set, then the form field’s widget will be set to Select, with choices coming from the model field’s choices. The choices will normally include the blank choice which is selected by default. If the field is required, this forces the user to make a selection. The blank choice will not be included if the model field has blank=False and an explicit default value (the default value will be initially selected instead).